# Creating embedded web browser or iframe in Excel Javascript API

Tags: javascript, excel, ggplot2, bokeh, office-js

I'm trying to create an Office-JS project which will take some form data, which i've created inside a Excel Taskpane Form.  Then when they submit it will send a request to my website which will process the form and spit back some HTML/JS as strings for Bokeh or ggplot.

Thus my question:  Is there a way to create an "embedded" `iframe` or `Microsoft web browser` that I can put `html/js` into and send the "left side" with `context.sync()` using the Excel JS API?

I've found documentation about using the built in graphs, but I was hoping to pass back more complex graphs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-charts

Something like this:
[image]

To put it into code, this is where i'm stuck:

```
function getData(){
     return Excel.run( function (context) {
         return context.sync().then( function () {

         .ajax({
             <my url and form data>

         }).done( function(data, status, xhr) {
             var browser = create_browser(); // I do not know what this would be

             // Bokeh route returns data["script"] & data["div"]
             // (\n<script type="text/javascript">\n ... <div class="bk-plotdiv" id="30d5b5cf-da07-4382-9b93-09ac605ba96d"></div>\n</div>)

             browser.render(data["script"], data["div"])
             sheet.getRange().values = browser
         })
    })
})
```

Comment: I'm not following your scenario here. Excel Web Add-ins _always_ run within an embedded browser or iframe (depending on the platform). It's fundamentally how they work.

Comment: See the edited paint image.

Comment: Again, this is fundamentally how Office Web Add-ins work. What error/blocker are you running into?

Comment: I'm sorry then, what's the function, or some documentation I can read, for manipulating browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you might want is a Content add-in. This is an example of one: [Excel Content Add-in Humongous-Insurance](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Content-Add-in-Humongous-Insurance). Some more information at [Create new objects in Office documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins#create-new-objects-in-office-documents). But you can't have both a browser in a task pane and one in the Excel document. These are different add-in types and the add-in manifest specifies the type. You will need to have the form as well as the resulting graphic in the content window.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to create a browser in both, thank you, looks like i'm just sticking with the content side.

Answer (score 0):

David E. Craig describes a way of communicating between a Task Pane Office app and a Content Office app (what would be embedded on the spreadsheet) on [his website](https://theofficecontext.com/2020/06/15/communication-between-office-web-add-ins/). He summarizes it as follows:

> The solution is to use the Document as a communication medium. In the particular case we used CustomXMLParts in the document. Here is how it would work:

> One add-in would need to send an update to the other, so it would write a CustomXMLPart with a specific namespace and a “context” (basically, I am the TaskPane communicating) to the document.

> Both add-ins will have a window.setInterval() thread running to check the documents for CustomXMLParts in that given namespace.

> The timer on the Content Add-in would fire, find the new customXMLPart from the taskpane, read the contents and then update itself as needed and finally, delete the CustomXMLPart.